# Is this a correct ellipsis in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

So, I'm writing this sentence:

> For some strange and, one would say, unrelated reason *my computer
>   failed to boot properly afterwards, and hasn't been able to since.*

What am I leaving out here? **To boot properly** or **to fail to boot properly**?

Comment: Hasn't been able to *what*?  Hasn't been able to fail?

Comment: I'm trying to say: hasn't been able to boot properly since.

Comment: The "omission" is simply the phrase left out of the statement because it's there *virtually*.

Comment: But are there no rules as to what part of the sentence is there virtually? You can't just leave out random phrases, of course.

Comment: I think you have omitted correctly here.  It infers that [it] hasn't been able to [boot properly] since.  :::edit::: (Also, I would be inclined to place 'one would say' into parentheses).

Comment: Thanks for the parentheses tip, I wasn't sure about that myself.

Comment: *Omit* is a transitive verb. I've edited the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For some strange and, one would say, unrelated reason my computer failed to boot properly afterwards, and hasn't been able to X since.

Since this is negative:

> hasn't been able to X since.

X can't be *fail to boot* because you'd be saying it did NOT fail to boot, which would mean it booted successfully, so then your whole sentence would contradict itself.

So X is *boot properly*.

In the usual context the sentence as written is fine.  However, if you were talking about other things regarding your computer in the same paragraph or conversation, there could be confusion, and at least *boot* should be there.  Example:

> My computer is fast and loads Photoshop quickly.  Then it stopped loading Photoshop.  Also, one day it didn't boot properly, and never did since that day.

I don't really know if *never did* refers to not booting or not loading Photoshop, from here, I'd glean you'd probably mean it didn't boot properly since that's the last thing mentioned, but there could be confusion.

Comment: It would have been better if the downvoter had left a reason.

Comment: So you're saying the sentence is gramatically correct, because otherwise it would logically contradict itself?

Comment: The sentence is fine, if a bit convoluted.  Not sure why this answer was given, since' fail' modifies' to boot' and 'hasn't been able to' refers to 'to boot' and so as written, the sentence is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I personally consider breaking the sentence when unable to construct a big one. Here is how I would say it:

> For some strange, and somewhat unrelated reason, my computer failed to boot properly afterwards. It hasn't been able to boot since then.

**Beware**: I'm new to grammar myself so my answer might be completely wrong.

Comment: Your advice is sound, and your answer contains the answer to the OP's question, even though you do not directly address the question asked. :)

Comment: @ Phoenix : When you are not sure, do not answer.

Comment: @serenesat But why not?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The sentence is better broken up. But I'd still like to know whether I'm omitting correctly, here.

Comment: Because it can mislead OP and others.

Comment: Actually, I think writing answers can sometimes be a great way to learn, especially if you're not completely sure. When you explain something to others, _you_ tend to learn it extremely well, because your empathy for the reader leads you to consider the topic more thoroughly than you normally would just by yourself. If you make a mistake, people here _will_ add comments to your answer, pointing it out and (sometimes) suggesting ways to fix it. Even some of the most sophisticated answerers here sometimes make mistakes, and they're always learning new and unexpected things.

Comment: @BenKovitz Though I agree with you (teaching is a great way to learn), I don't think it's really a good idea to write answers to learn here on ELL. For one thing, people who know better aren't always there to correct wrong answers. Another thing is, by answering more, a user will usually get more rep points, which in turn could lead learners to believe that their answers are correct. (Sometimes we as a community help turn a blatantly wrong answer into a correct one. Nothing wrong with that, but the answerer'd accumulate rep points, which in turn could give a false illusion.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. How'd you like to raise this topic on meta? It's surely too subtle and complex to consider fully in comments. In brief, though, here's another way to look at it: Error is often _beneficial_ and should be welcomed, because it opens an opportunity for correction—an important part of learning, which doesn't happen without error. See also [this](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/1327/6700). (I think rep numbers are mostly for fun, not to be taken seriously. That might be a whole 'nother meta topic.)

Comment: @BenKovitz I sure know that "error" is beneficial to each individual. About rep points, we are on the same page. (Why else I've answered so few questions when I spend so much time on ELL?) However, I'd like to ask you to try to pretend that you don't know English as much as you do; let's say everything on this website was in ancient Chinese, and you'd learned it about half way through. How could you know which answer is correct? Would you really ignore the rep points of the answerers? As for the meta, it's an interesting idea. I'd be happy if you raise it on our meta site (if you want to).

Comment: @DamkerngT. Excellent point about naïve readers needing some "out of band" information to tell wrong answers from right. I will indeed give that more weight in my thinking. (About raising "Should we discourage people from posting answers they're not sure of?" on meta, I'd prefer not to if the topic isn't especially pressing, and it appears that it's not.)